# Getting only ID from entity relations without fetching whole object in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Assume I've an entity, which references itself to map parent-child-relations

```
class Food
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Food", inversedBy="foodChildren")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="food_group_id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $foodGroup;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Food", mappedBy="foodGroup", fetch="LAZY", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    protected $foodChildren;
```

I have a use case where I want to get `food_group_id` of an entity without getting full parent object from database. Using `fetch="LAZY"` doesn't keep Doctrine from querying again. Is there a way to return only the ID when getting `$food->getFoodGroup()`?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Don't complicate your life, you can just do

```
$food->getFoodGroup()->getId()
```

This **WILL NOT** perform any additional query or trigger lazy load!

This is because your `$food->foodGroup` is a proxy object which knows about it's ID. It will only do lazy load if you call a getter method of some field which hasn't been loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the background (substantiated with proxy objects)! (I think the problem with lazy load was accessing some getter methods, like you've written, which is not necessary anymore).

Comment: Can someone explain why you don't have access to the variable $food->getFoodGroupId()? I have a similar case, where I explicitly set `protected $viewVersionId` and refer to that as the `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="viewVersionId", referencedColumnName="id") and I have a getter for `getViewVersionId()` that returns `$this->viewVersionId` but it returns NULL. I am forced to call getViewVersion()->getId(). Why is that?

Comment: Nevermind. You CAN do what I assumed you should be able to (see my answer below, with a reference to another question I posted on this).

Comment: Remember, that this will only work, if your getId()-method complies with rules defined in [https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php#L839](Doctrine's code). In particular, the method should be not more than 4 lines long and the id field should be named in accordance to the method: getId() will use $this->id and getIdentiFier() will use $this->identiFier. Double check your CamelCase!

Comment: Thanks for this! And a remark - in case the main entity's property is nullable, this is not safe to do, so in that case it may be better to go with Noquepoaqui's solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19142003/261332

Comment: This works nice but I've seen that if you use another method name for the id getter such as `$food->getFoodGroup()->id()`it doesn't work. Does any way to indicate to doctrine the id getter method name to use?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to define the ID field, associate it with the ORM, and then create the getter for that field, and it *should* work.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Food", inversedBy="foodChildren")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foodGroupId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $foodGroup;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $foodGroupId;

public function getFoodGroupId() {
    return $this->foodGroupId;
}
```

Note, I changed the field name in my example to Pascal Case, for consistency. Also, I'm new to Symfony, but your ManyToOne association mapping seems odd. I'm not sure why you have nullable on the entity (I just haven't seen that before). You don't have a referencedColumnName="id", but maybe that is just because it defaults to "id" (I like to be explicit). See [Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional).

I had a very [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639787/cannot-access-the-saved-id-of-the-associated-entity-directly-without-getting-ent), which was caused just because I hadn't associated that field with the ORM. So you should know that it IS possible to call:

```
$food = $em->getRepository("AcmeFoodBundle:Food")->find($id);
$food->getFoodGroupId();
```

Comment: This should work, although you'll have to be careful with updates: anything that sets `$this->foodGroupId` will also have to update `$this->foodGroup`, and vice versa, or else Doctrine will get confused by having two different values for the same field when it goes to persist the entity.

Comment: Well this is extra, isn't it? The `$food->getFoodGroup()->getId()` call does what is needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
$em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityIdentifier(...);
```

to get id's without making joins.

In your example it would be something like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$food = $em->getRepository('HungryHungryBundle:Food')->findOneById($id);
print_r($em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityIdentifier($food->getFoodGroup())); 
die();
```

This way you will get the food_group_id without making an extra join.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is a performance issue and you're trying to limit queries but why not just do something like this in your getter (I'm assuming that's your Food entity using Doctrine ORM Annotations):

```
class Food
{
    ...
    public function getFoodGroup() {
        $foodGroup = $this->getFoodGroup();

        return $foodGroup->getId();
    }
```

or even better name it appropriately `getFoodGroupId()`

Comment: Not just better, you **must** to select another name, because infinite recursion