# Get Entity subobject id without joining or new sql request

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Example I have a Entity User which have a Contact. How I get the Contact ID without joining the contact table.

```
$user = $entityManager->userRepository->findUserById(1);
$contactId = $user->getContact()->getId();
```

when `getContact() is called the whole contact is loaded from the DB. How I can avoid this SQL request without add a join in findUserById. I only need to contactId which is in my users table, but there is no simple function like $user->getContactId().

Comment: You basically can't, at least not without some hacking.  Doctrine 2's Object Relation Manager deals with objects, not ids.  I know it's a bit of a conceptual step and the extra join might seem bothersome but use it the way it the way it was designed.  If there are still issues then drop down to the database access layer and use sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this post [Getting only ID from entity relations without fetching whole object in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139970/getting-only-id-from-entity-relations-without-fetching-whole-object-in-doctrine). I tested a simple example in a ManyToOne relation and the related object was not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation sounds perfect for the Doctrine Second Level Cache

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/second-level-cache.html

With this, the first query will be gotten from DB but every subsequent query will be from the second level cache, plus if you change the data using doctrine then the cache is automatically updated. For this reason, I suggest you set a very long time for the cache my personal favourite is 1 month approx 2592000 seconds.

Enable it in your user entity like so

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
* @ORM\Cache(usage="NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE", region="users_region")
* @ORM\Table(
*   name="site_users",
*   indexes={
*       @ORM\Index(name="username_index", columns={"username"}),
*       @ORM\Index(name="email_index", columns={"email"}),
*       @ORM\Index(name="enabled_index", columns={"enabled"}),
*       @ORM\Index(name="last_login_index", columns={"last_login"})
*   }
*)
*/
class User extends BaseUser 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

......

Then in your config.yml like so

```
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                auto_mapping: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                second_level_cache:
                    enabled:            true
#                    region_lock_lifetime: 60
                    region_lifetime:    300
                    log_enabled:        %kernel.debug%
                    region_cache_driver: apc
                    regions: 
                        users_region: 
                            region_lifetime:    2592000
                            region_cache_driver: apc
```

............

More information here

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html

Note this method also ensure that the popular check for an authenticated user `$user = $this->getUser();` does not hit your DB as well.

Comment: Thank you. Thats a nice feature. In my current project I cant use because the web application runs on different server which access the same db server. So the cache expiring would not work when updating an entity on the other server.

Comment: Then you should use a distributed cache like redis or memcache. With the second level cache, any update to an entity via the entity manager would automatically update the cache whether local or distributed :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change fetch mode in the specific query, as described [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql) in the doc.

So you can describe your query as follow:

```
// Supposing this method in the repository class
public function findUserById($idUser)
{
$qb =  $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where("u.id = :idUser")
        ->setParameter("idUser", $idUser);

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        // Describe here all the entity and the association name that you want to fetch eager
        $query->setFetchMode("YourBundle\\Entity\\Contract", "contract", ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
        ...

return $qb->->getResult();
}
```

NB:

> Changing the fetch mode during a query is only possible for one-to-one
>   and many-to-one relations.

Hope this help

Comment: If I understand EAGER right it will still join the contact table or not? I dont want an extra join because the contact_id is on the user table.

Comment: no, but now i understand what you need and my solution don't solve your problem, sorry

Comment: I suppose is a oneToone relation, try adding on it the FETCH=EAGER directive  `fetch="EAGER"`Hope this help